# Date conversion in SAS (String to Date)

Tags: sorting, date, sas

I import an Excel-spreadsheet using the following SAS-procedure.

```
%let datafile = 'Excel.xlsx'
%let tablename = myDB

proc import datafile  =  &datafile   
    out  =  &tablename
    dbms  =  xlsx
    replace
     ;
run;
```

One of the variables (`date_variable`) has the format DD.MM.YYYY. Therefore, I was defining a new format like this:

```
data &tablename;
    set &tablename;
    format date_variable mmddyy10.;
run;
```

Now, I would like to sort the table by that variable:

```
proc sort data = &tablename;
  by date_variable;
run;
```

However, as the `date_variable` is defined as a string, I dont get the sorting right. How can I re-define the `date_variable` as a date?

Answer (score 2):

`format date_variable mmddyy10.;` does not convert a string to a date. It just sets a format for displaying that field etc.

Essentially I think what you are saying is date_variable is a string that looks like "31.01.2019". If that is the case, you will have to first convert it into a date value:

```
date_variable_converted = input(date_variable, DDMMYY10.);
```

You should be now able to sort using date_variable_converted which is a SAS date value.

Comment: Note that there is no need to change the delimiter in the string before reading it with the DDMMYY informat.  It should handle most commonly used delimiters.

Comment: @Tom Updated the answer. Didn't know that 'dots' will be recognized by this informat also.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `input` function to convert the string-value containing a date representation to a date-value that can have a date-style format applied to it that will affect how the date-value is rendered in output and viewers.

The `input` function requires an *informat* as an argument.  Check the [format documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/64790/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0verk17pchh4vn1akrrv0b5w3r0.htm), which includes an entry for:

> **DDMMYYw. Informat**
>   Reads date values in the form ddmmyy or dd-mm-yy, where a special character, such as a hyphen (-), period (.), or slash (/), separates the day, month, and year; the year can be either 2 or 4 digits.

Example:

```
* string values contain date representations;
data have;
  input date_from_excel $10.;
  cards;
31.01.2019
01.02.2019
15.01.2019
run;

data want;
  set have;
  date = input(date_from_excel, ddmmyy10.);  * convert to SAS date values;
  format date ddmmyyd10.;                    * format to apply when rendering those values;
run;

* sort by SAS date values;
proc sort data=want;
  by date;
run;
```