# Date to string conversion inside global SAS variable definition

Tags: string, date, sas

I am aiming to concatenate a long directory string within a global SAS variable without using an additional data step. I have the following code:

```
%let deadline='31Dec2019'd;
%let rootDir=Y:\PD;
%let timestamp=input(&deadline.,yymmdd8.);
%let PATH=&rootDir\currentStats\&timestamp.;
%put &PATH.--;
```

This gives me an error which confuses me:

> Open code statement recursion detected.

I also tried `%input`, `%put`, and `put` instead of `input`, but always the same error. I am still not too fluent in SAS, so forgive me this noobish question, but I do not find any working solution on the web and seems like it has not beenasked yet here, either.

Resources which did not solve my issue:

- https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Convert-Date-to-Character/td-p/349562
- https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Converting-date-to-Character/td-p/90392
- [Date conversion in SAS (String to Date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885193/date-conversion-in-sas-string-to-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Evaluate your date literal source snippet as a date value.
- Use format `B8601DA8.` to render the date value as *yyyymmdd*

SAS Macro can utilize Base functions via the `%sysfunc` macro function.

The syntax is

```
%let result = %sysfunc ( <function-name> ( <arg-1>, ... ) );
```

In macro a string literal is passed to a function ***without*** enclosing it literally in single quotes.  Why? Because macro at it's core is a string only processing system with possible code writing side effects.

**Your changes**

The macro variable contains literally a source code for date literal.  You need to evalutate that as a date value and then format the result to the filename part construct needed (*yy-mm-dd*)

```
%let deadline='31Dec2019'd;
%let ymd_str=%sysfunc(putn(&deadline,yymmdd6.));

%put &=deadline;
%put &=ymd_str;
---------- Log ----------
DEADLINE='31Dec2019'd
YMD_STR=191231
```

There are different date representations that might be the actual part of your filenames.  Here as some possibilities:

```
/*  date representation construct according to ----> format */
%put yymmdd   : %sysfunc(putn(&deadline,  yymmdd6.));
%put yy-mm-dd : %sysfunc(putn(&deadline,  yymmdd8.));
%put yyyymmdd : %sysfunc(putn(&deadline,  B8601DA8.));
%put yyyymmdd : %sysfunc(putn(&deadline,  YYMMDDN8.));

----- log -----

yymmdd   : 191231
yy-mm-dd : 19-12-31
yyyymmdd : 20191231
yyyymmdd : 20191231
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and conclusive answer. Just one follow-up question: What do I have to change in your code to get dates as `yyyymmdd`?

Comment: The nested `%sysevalf()` function calls are not needed inside of `%sysfunc()` calls.